# Best Table Sorter Not Jquery?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

which one is best table sorter choice i wanted to do

- Default filter
- Sorting
- Pagination
- Filter

Which one is the best choice for the table filtering that do above all things?? and Most Important Not Jquery one...!!

Comment: do you have a problem with all js libraries, or did jquery just do something particularly awful to you in the past?

Comment: yep Jquery give me bad time always with its conflicts and sometime compatibility

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using : [Table_Sort](http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the dojo DataGrid.

The DataGrid (and all related classes/widgets) are separated from the actual data so you can put a filter on the data source in any way you would want. There is a big choice of data stores like a REST store or a simple CSV store.

Sorting can be done in the grid itself, delegated to the store or delegated to the server. Depending on what your need it is it might be wise to sort your set on the server to keep performance high in the browsers.

The page does do paging but not in the conventional way that you can flick through the pages. There might be a plug-in component on the grid to make that possible though but I don't know. The current implementation just renders the pages that are visible and when you scroll it will render additional pages.

For more info and examples: 
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/index?action=show&redirect=dojox/grid

In my experience with dojo grid I think you will be best off using the dojox.grid.Enhanced grid. It is a bit faster then the DataGrid and new plug-ins and features are constantly added. And with a bit of reading and hanging out in #dojo it is quite possible to write your own plug-in.